# solve for e (variable) in all variable equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused about this problem because my professor never went over it:

How would I solve for $e$ in this equation

$$\frac{E}{e} =\frac{ (R+r)}{r}$$

A step by step explanation would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Take reciprocals of both sides, then multiply both sides by $E$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: $$\frac{E}{e} =\frac{ (R+r)}{r} \to e(R+r)=rE \\\to e=\frac{rE}{R+r}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac Ee &= \frac{R+r}{r} \\
E &= e \cdot \frac{R+r}{r} \\
Er &= e \cdot (R+r) \\
\frac{Er}{R+r} &= e \\
\end{align}$$